# Data Storage in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Data is hashed before getting stored in the Fabric. My fabric application uses Couchdb. When I opened the port on which couchdb is live , it showed data in JSON format which could be modified so how can I prevent this modification??

and most importantly where is the hashed data stored in Fabric application???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent such modification since one you able to get connected to the CouchDB you basically able to rewrite everything and no one actually could prevent you. However that being said, with strong endorsement policy you can actually mitigate the influence of such data tampering. For example if you can define endorsement policy to be

```
AND(Org1.member, Org2.member)
```

and say someone forged endorsing peer of the Org1 and changed record in CouchDB, application doing endorsement will be able to detect inconsistency of the endorsement response. For example to make it even stronger you can define endorsement policy which will require endorsement from two peers of each organization, therefore making it less likely for attacker to succeed.

> and most importantly where is the hashed data stored in Fabric application???????

The hashed data stored in the blockchain, not in the state DB, state DB only reflects changes accepted by recent block commit.